# Is it possible stream image data from server to html?

Tags: java, javascript, server-side

Suppose I have the src of an image. I want to first load the image data onto my server, and then do some processing on it, and then return it to my html for display. Is it possible to do this? 
I am not allowed to store the processed file on the server and then refer that in the `src` attribute.

I am using a Java/Groovy server.

Comment: You can set a servlet as the `src` of the image. You pass a parameter in the URL to identify the image you want to process and there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all as you probably know you will have to use a HTML form to POST the image to your servlet.

The servlet then can process it and return the image (content-type = image/jpeg)  in the outputstream of the response.

```
byte[] imageBytes = getImageAsBytes();
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
response.setContentLength(imageBytes.length);
response.getOutputStream().write(imageBytes);
```

Comment: and as Balint Bako mentions, you can set the src of the img tag to point to the servlet

Comment: But as you mentioned you do not want to store the image on the server.  So the servlet can not access the client to get the image unless you upload it.  After you have uploaded it you could use the servlet src trick, but then this would be two requests and as the servlet is not stateful you would have to save if on the server.

Comment: the image exists on a different server.. i have the URL. i pass the url as a parameter to the servlet (from within the image tag's `src`), then I can just load file data in the servlet, obtain a `bufferedImage`, process it and return it back to the tag

Comment: Yep, if the image is not on the client, that should be sweet